# Armature and mesh deform because of new objects added to scene despite not being parented. Blender 3.4 alpha

Tags: armature, parent

I have a simple animated character and created an armature with the skin modifier. Created a walk cycle and am ready to flesh out the scene. The issue is that every time I add a new object it is somehow "ghost" parented to the armature and any movement/scaling breaks the existing armature. For instance add>mesh>plane and then moving the plane will pull the bones around and break the mesh. I have examined the added objects and they claim not to be parented to anything. I can't find any info for this on here or on google and would really appreciate any help if anyone knows whats happening I'd like to avoid having to start over and potentially run into the same issues. [image: This is a simple plane added through the menu and a fresh installation of the 3.4 alpha and it still breaks the armature despite not being parented]

Comment: Hello, you have activated the Proportional Editing option, maybe it's your problem here?

Comment: Weirdly 2 things worked for this, what you just suggested and I dont see why because i thought that only worked on what was selected but thinking about how it affects unselected vertices in edit mode that makes sense! ALSO for whatever reason it appears that i can add the plane, parent to camera, clear the parent and that worked because it jumped the plane far enough away without deforming the mesh that it had no proportional effect. Not because of some ghost parenting that i was convinced of. Thank you I feel ridiculous.

Answer (score 5):

Disable the *Proportional Editing* option:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the awesome response time and for not being rude about what I'm sure is a common mistake. Happy blending